# Access ExtendedProperties on resources that do not belong to logged in user

Tags: exchange-server, office365, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

**TL;DR version**

Is there any way to access `ExtendedProperties` on a resources that does not belong to the logged in user from an Outlook add-in?

---

**Detailed version**

We are setting `ExtendedProperties` on a `CalendarFolder` associated with a resource. We tried to access these `ExtendedProperties` from our Outlook add-in, however, since the `CalendarFolder` does not belong to the logged in user,  the Outlook JavaScript API returned with an error when we used: `mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync()`

> Office extension have no permissions to access any other mailboxes
>   then the mailbox provided in the user context

The logged in user does have owner permissions on the `CalendarFolder` for the resource (`Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity RoomResource@domain.com:\calendar -User admin -AccessRights Owner`)

We are able to access the `ExtendedProperties` as expected when we create a simple console app and use the .NET Managed API, so we figured we could call the same EWS endpoint (/EWS/Exchange.asmx) from our add-in.

We first get an access token (using `mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync`) and pass that with our call to the EWS endpoint directly from our add-in.

When we make an AJAX call to that endpoint, we are getting a 401 Unauthorized response from Exchange with the header:

`x-ms-diagnostics:2000001;reason="The callback token is missing one or more expected claim types.";error_category="invalid_token"`

**Question**

Is it possible to call the /EWS/Exchange.asmx endpoint on Exchange (on-prem and online) using oAuth? If so, how can we get a valid token that will validate. Can we ask for additional claims when requesting a token?